# java jar getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream return nullpointerexception

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classloader, inputstream

Image:
[This is my Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoHST.png)

In MainRun class, i have the following code:

```
package bin;
public class MainRun{
   public static void main(String[] args){

    compileCode("Square.java");

    int length = 0;
    MCAMClassLoader classLoader = new MCAMClassLoader();
    Class<?> c= classLoader.findClass(bin.Square);

    try{
        Shape myClassObject = (Shape)c.newInstance();
        Method method = c.getMethod(getLength);
        Object result = method.invoke(myClassObject);
        length = (int)result;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(length);
  }

  public void compileCode(String _filename){
     String[] args = new String[] {"-d", "C:\Users\Tan\Downloads\MCAM", "C:\Users\Tan\Downloads\MCAM\src\"+_filename};
    com.sun.tools.javac.Main javac = new com.sun.tools.javac.Main();
    javac.compile(args);
  }
}
```

In my custom ClassLoader, i have the following code:

```
package bin;
public class MCAMClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
  @Override
  public Class<?> findClass(String name) 
  {
      byte[] bt = loadClassData(name);
      return defineClass(name, bt, 0, bt.length);
  }

  private byte[] loadClassData(String className) {

    InputStream is =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(className.replace(".", "/")+".class"); //it will end up with bin/Square.class
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteSt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int len =0;
    try 
    {
        while((len=is.read())!=-1)
        {
            byteSt.write(len);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteSt.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

And i have my Square class added and compiled on run time. Square.class will be located in bin folder.

```
package bin;
public class Square extends Shape{

  public Square(){
    length = 8;
  }

  public int getLength(){
    return length;
  }
}
```

These codes work perfectly fine when it was executed by .bat on console. Only when i build those files into a jar file and run it, I will get the error on the console: NullPointerException which fall on the line "while((len=is.read())!=-1)".

Note: in my MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: bin.MainRun
Class-Path: .\lib\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar .\lib\tools.jar
```

**Why?** Am I using the ClassLoader incorrectly? Something else? Please advise and thanks in advance

Comment: `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()` doesn't return a NullPointerException() (which it can't) but later when you use the returned InputStream you experience a NPE...

Comment: Are you sure that the path you pass to the `getResourceAsStream` is correct? Have you checked the `.jar` itself?

Comment: Try adding an additonal "/" in front of all of it

Comment: @petrbel yes, it was correct. It work perfectly fine only when i run it on the console e.g java MainRun.

Comment: @3kings Tried and it gave the same error

Comment: Try to use File.pathSeparator instead of / in the replace()

like - className.replace(".", File.pathSeparator)+".class"

Comment: @j.htan Make sure it looks either like `\bin\Square.class` or `/bin/Square.class`. Im pretty sure though its the second one.

Answer (score 0):

There are (often) no directories inside jar files. Therefore it will return null.

If you want to get the file you could get that resource directly:

```
InputStream fileInputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(File.pathSeparator+className+".class");
```

Comment: do i need to include my package name? e.g. getClass().getResourceAsStream(File.pathSeparator+"package"+File.pathSeparato+className+".class");

Comment: @j.htan the file or the resource you are using must be accessible.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it still not working. Are you sure it is suppose to be File.pathSeparator instead for File.separator? As File.pathSeparator  = ";" while File.separator = "\"

Comment: @j.htan oops. that would be File.separator. I didn't check the code.